# jquery/javascript the best practice for smoothest animation on keydown/mousedown

Tags: jquery, animation, smoothing

What's the best way to do this,

- with `setTimeout() and css({left: '+=1'});`

or

- using the `animation({left:+=30}, '300', 'linear');`

As much as I think that setTimeout and css() is the right way, I can't seem to achieve the right smoothness with it, not to mention that is seems to eat memory alot..

*Note that I'm not trying to animation on mousedown and stop on mouseup, not animation from one point to another on click.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animate() increases values by tenths, that's why it's smoother.

Guess you could do the same with  css(), but why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the jQuery animate is the best way.

A lot of work has been put in the jQuery library to create very smooth animations. I've tried to work with both, but I have always come to the conclusion that animation with the jQuery library is better then writing your own code for animation.

In my opinion, it's also the easiest way to implement such animation.

EDIT: if you only have to work with the latest browsers, CSS3 is also a good way for animating: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/.

Comment: The thing is, when you are using animate, you have to animate at least a few pixels, so without actually holding the button down, just doing the click, it will animate those few pixels.. You know what I mean, it's unlike using the css and settimeout method, where it wouldn't animate at all or animate just one pixel.. and nope, on this particular project I can't use CSS3..

Comment: If you don't want to animate your html, than you obviously shouldn't use the jQuery animate function.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLfYX/) try to click only, without holding the button down, animate animates those 10pxs, which is rather unwanted effect, and to get that smoothness and consistent fps from animate, you can't do animate({left:'+=1'})

Comment: ow yes, now i understand. Then it is probably better to use css3 or the setTimeout-function.